# TO_DATE function Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I am trying to select data from a certain date from range, but not within a certain set of parameters.

Currently:

```
SELECT external_reporting_id AS asin,
       last_updated          AS "Received"
  FROM transfer_delivery_items
 WHERE last_updated >= TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY') - 13
 ORDER BY last_updated DESC;
```

But I would want to see everything NOT in that date range.
 I have tried `>= TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY')-13`, but it doesn't look like it is an approved format, or even possible if anything can lend me a hand that'd be great.

Comment: `to_date()` converts a **string** to a **date**. `sysdate` *is* already a date. So it's *totally* useless to apply `to_date()` on `date` value to `convert` it to a `date` value. It's actually even worse: because this way the `date` value `sysdate` gets converted to a string value first (subject to implicit NLS settings) just to be converted back to a `date` again.

Comment: I was under the impression I had to to convert to the date format. When I remove sysdate, I receive error, and when I remove sysdate, and 'DD-MON-YYYY' I receive errors. So, I've always used them on this db.

Comment: A `date` does not have a "format". So there is no need to "convert" it. In your case `last_updated >= sysdate - 13` should work just fine. Probably better to use `trunc(last_updated) >= trunc(sysdate) - 14` to ignore the time part of the `date` values.

Comment: Would this work?<br/>                                               select external_reporting_id ASIN, last_updated as "Received" from transfer_delivery_items
where last_updated <= trunc(sysdate)-13 or last_updated >= trunc(sysdate)+13
order by last_updated desc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysdate is already a date, so if you want everything 13 days prior do:

```
select external_reporting_id ASIN, last_updated as "Received" 
  from transfer_delivery_items
 where last_updated >= trunc(sysdate) -13
 order by last_updated desc;
```

The `trunc(sysdate)` will remove the time from the date, to encompass all records 13 days prior.

Note: I would not do

```
trunc(last_updated) >= trunc(sysdate)
```

because `last_updaetd` is probably an indexed column and `trunc(last_update)` will bypass that index.  (unless there is a function index on `trunc(last_updated)`.

### Update:

To get the block of dates 13 days prior and no more than 13 days into the future do:

```
select external_reporting_id ASIN, last_updated as "Received" 
  from transfer_delivery_items
 where last_updated >= trunc(sysdate) -13
   and last_updated <= trunc(sysdate) +13
 order by last_updated desc;
```

Comment: What if I wanted everything AT least 13 days prior, and at least 13 days ahead. And black out today +13 and today -13?

Answer (score 0):

It think you can NOT the BETWEEN:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147

I don't have an Oracle instance available to me or I'd test this out.  I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Wouldn't that specify me to set a date range? Or, what dates I want?

Comment: When I do this : where last_updated not between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate)-13 I still receive the data between the dates hmm..

Comment: I recommend you forget about sysdate, trunc, and the like for now.  I think you aren't working with the DATE values you think you are working with.  BETWEEN has always worked for me.